# How to package a sharepoint project (Sharepoint server 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I work on a Sharepoint Server 2013 project, I want to know if there is a method to make this project (package) that I can work on any machine (at home)

Answer (score 0):

you must have the sharepoint 2013 foundation or enterprise version installed on your machine. Then you can simple publish the project and in that way you can take your project to your local sharepoint environment.

If you want to take the list and any other columns or anything like that to your local environment then you can back up and restore the Content database in local environment.

Please let me know if this helps or you will require any other details regarding this

Thanks

Comment: 10'x Bro SigarDave Yeah that was very helpfull i know that i need to publish my site.  but i dont know how import the site in local sharepoint ??

Comment: if my answer helps you then upvote and/or mark it as answer . Or you will need more details please let me know